# Second form not getting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this single page application that instead of pages, loads sections one at a time. The basics of this app is that you input a query and then go a results page, and on top of the results in another form - same as the first form but instead of going to a new view (into a different section of the same page) the results just appear below it. Whenever a new view loads, the other is hidden. (ex: home view has search form. Search, submit, hides home view and then results view)

The data is from a remote server with Ajax.

EDIT: Thanks to @Himal, I fixed the first issue. However now when I enter something in the second form, it just returns "Nothing was submitted". I'm not sure why it does that even though I did input something. Any reason why?

Old (FIXED!) problem:

However, the problem is that the first form works. You search a query and then the results are shown on the results view, however, when you search again using the form that's above the results view, it doesn't do anything. Here is the code:

```
getPickerData = function() {
    var tickerForm = $('#analyze-form'),
        pickHolder = $('#PickHolder'), // The view where the results and second form resides
        pickContent = $('#PickHolder #pick-content'); // Where the results is loaded
        tickerHomeVal = $('#home #ticker').val(); // Value of the first ticker
    //document.getElementById('PickHolder').innerHTML='<h3 class="loadingtext">Loading Data</h3>';
    //document.getElementById('PickHolder').style.display='';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: 'http://differenturl.com/something.php', 
            data: "something="+tickerHomeVal+"&something",
        complete: function(data){  
            pickContent.html(data.responseText);
        }  
    });

    var tickerResultsVal = $('#PickHolder #ticker').val();
    $('#results-submit-ticker').on('touchstart click', function(e){
        console.log('clicked?');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: 'http://differenturl.com/something.php', 
            data: "something="+tickerResultsVal+"&something",
            complete: function(data){   
               pickContent.html(data.responseText);
               console.log(data);
            }  
        });
    });
}
```

The second ajax call is for the second form. The click event is here. The return false s there so the button doesn't change view.

```
var viewchange = $('.toview');

viewchange.on('touchstart click', function(event){
    var $this = $(this);

        doAction($this); // runs the function above with a bunch of unrelated if's.
         return false;
});
```

That's pretty much it. There is a if statement that looks for a certain class to run this function but I think that is un-relevant.

HTML looks like this, for the second form. Which is exactly the same as the first form, only difference here that it's in a different view as well as a div below it for the results.

```
<div id="PickHolder" class="view container">
    <form id="analyze-results-form" action="" class="analyze-form">
        <div class="input-container">
            <input id="ticker" class="input-stock" type="text" placeholder="Add Ticker">

        </div><!-- /.input-container -->
        <button id="results-submit-ticker" class="action action-data btn no-view" data-ref="#PickHolder">Analyze</button>
    </form>
    <div id="pick-content"></div>
</div>
```

As well as different ids, as you can tell by the JS.

Why doesn't the JS for section form  not return the data? The console.log() doesn't even happen for the click.

Comment: Hi @Himal Thanks for looking at this, I really appreciate it. But yes, but that really doesn't matter. I changed it to that and it had no effect as well.

Comment: Yes, i realized it. that's why i removed the comment.

Comment: @Himal Is it possible you can help me figure out this issue? I really need too!

Comment: why aren't you using `$('#results-submit-ticker').on('touchstart click',function(e)..` for your click event ?. added: also you might wanna use jQuery 'success' callback instead of 'complete'.you can use 'error' callback to report any errors.

Comment: I thought because pickcontent will be pulling in ajax specific content, I'll need it.. Thanks I changed it to the normal way and I can not get something on the results page, however I still got one more issue. I'll be editing this post. Hope you can help with that too.

Comment: I cannot tell why but i know that it is common mistake to recreate an event bound item in javascript makes it loses its bindings. So may you be recreating your pick-content on first ajax call?

Comment: Dont use a variable for the input value. Instead of tickerresultsvar use $('#PickHolder #ticker').val(); this

Comment: add `tickerResultsVal = $('#PickHolder #ticker').val();` after the `on('touchstart click', function(e){..` line.when you first initialized the variable your input field is empty. added: you can also use the @Azadrum's method.

Comment: Thanks you two. One more question. The results are loaded in a table, the table html is from the data of the results server. First results works, but when using the results page to search, the second column of results (its a two column table) jumps to the center. Any idea what's causing that?

Comment: you might wanna create a new question for that.

Comment: And someone should create an answer for this question. For good practice @Himal?

Comment: @Azadrum feel free to post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As himal suggests you should use success callback instead of completed for your ajax requests to be able to see if there is an error or it is completed successfully. So your ajax call should look like,

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: 'http://differenturl.com/something.php', 
            data: "something="+tickerResultsVal+"&something",
            success: function(data){   
               pickContent.html(data.responseText);
               console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, error) {
               // handle error
            }
});
```

Completed callback was hiding your underlying error of unset value of variable named tickerResultsVal.

You defined and set the value of tickerResultsVal outside the scope of your click event. So in the first run it is correctly set and send to ajax request. but in your second click;

```
var tickerResultsVal = $('#PickHolder #ticker').val();
```

is never run so the tickerResultsVal is unset that returns "Nothing was submitted" error from ajax request.

You can use the relative path to the value or put the definition of tickerResultsVal inside your click event

```
$('#results-submit-ticker').on('touchstart click', function(e){
    var tickerResultsVal = $('#PickHolder #ticker').val(); // inside the scope of click event
    console.log('clicked?');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: 'http://differenturl.com/something.php', 
        data: "something="+$('#PickHolder #ticker').val()+"&something", // or just use relative path to input value
        complete: function(data){   
           pickContent.html(data.responseText);
           console.log(data);
        }  
    });
});
```